# Compact letter display from logical matrix

Tags: r

I was wondering if there is a way to turn a logical matrix of comparisons into a letter notation as used in multiple comparisons test. As in `multcomp::cld`.

The data I have looks like this:

```
test_data <- data.frame(mean=c(1.48, 1.59, 1.81,1.94),CI_lower=c(1.29,1.38,1.54, 1.62),CI_upper=c(1.56,1.84, 2.3, 2.59))

  mean CI_lower CI_upper
1 1.48     1.29     1.56
2 1.59     1.38     1.84
3 1.81     1.54     2.30
4 1.94     1.62     2.59
```

What I am interested in is a notation that says which entries have overlapping CIs to get a final result that looks like this:

```
final <- data.frame(mean=c(1.48, 1.59, 1.81,1.94),CI_lower=c(1.29, 1.38,1.54, 1.62),CI_upper=c(1.56,1.84, 2.3, 2.59),letters = c("a","ab","ab","b"))

  mean CI_lower CI_upper letters
1 1.48     1.29     1.56       a
2 1.59     1.38     1.84      ab
3 1.81     1.54     2.30      ab
4 1.94     1.62     2.59       b
```

I made a pitiful attempt that went like this:

```
same <- outer(test_data$CI_lower, test_data$CI_upper,"-")
same <- same<0
same <- lower.tri(same, diag = FALSE) & same

same_ind <- which(same,arr.ind = T)

groups <- as.list(as.numeric(rep(NA,nrow(test_data))))

for(i in 1:nrow(same_ind)){
  group_pos <- as.numeric(same_ind[i,])
  for(i2 in group_pos){
    groups[[i2]] <- c(groups[[i2]],i)
  }
}

letters_notation <- sapply(groups,function(x){
  x <- x[!is.na(x)]
  x <- letters[x]
  x <- paste0(x,collapse="")
  return(x)
}
)
```

which would gives this:

```
  mean CI_lower CI_upper letters
1 1.48     1.29     1.56      ab
2 1.59     1.38     1.84     acd
3 1.81     1.54     2.30     bce
4 1.94     1.62     2.59      de
```

Any ideas for how to do this?

Comment: Not sure I understand desired output

Comment: What I want or what it means?
What I need is c("a","ab","ab","b").

It means that the first 3 entries all have overlapping CI. And the last 3 have overlapping CIs. While the first and last entry do not oevrlap.

Comment: I have a possible very efficient solution but not exactly your desired output, but you will be able to determine the overlapping paths, not sure if to post it or not

Comment: So why is the first entry "a" and not "ab" or "ac" ?  Why do you assign double-letters to some overlapping items and not others?

Comment: each letter defines a group with entries that cannot be separated from each other. "ab" means that it is included in both group a and b of entries that cannot be distinguished.
It is often used in statistics. You can see a more intuitive depiction here: https://www.researchgate.net/file.PostFileLoader.html?id=525556b4d11b8b0719c99e9e&key=3deec525556b4971cc

Comment: I think you need to take a look at [**igraph**](http://igraph.org/r/doc/igraph.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion! googling "R igraph multiple comparisons table" lead me to this: http://menugget.blogspot.it/2014/05/automated-determination-of-distribution.html
Adjusting the code there I was able to get what I wanted. I will post as a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From David Arenburg's suggestion and this http://menugget.blogspot.it/2014/05/automated-determination-of-distribution.html nice write-up I found a solution.

```
library(igraph)

test_data <- data.frame(mean=c(1.48, 1.59, 1.81,1.94),CI_lower=c(1.29,1.38,1.54, 1.62),CI_upper=c(1.56,1.84, 2.3, 2.59))

n <- nrow(test_data)


g <- outer(test_data$CI_lower, test_data$CI_upper,"-")
g <- !(g<0)
g <- g + t(g) # not necessary, but make matrix symmetric
g <- g!=1
rownames(g) <- 1:n # change row names
colnames(g) <- 1:n # change column names


# Re-arrange data into an "edge list" for use in igraph (i.e. which groups are "connected") - Solution from "David Eisenstat" ()
same <- which(g==1)
g2 <- data.frame(N1=((same-1) %% n) + 1, N2=((same-1) %/% n) + 1)
g2 <- g2[order(g2[[1]]),] # Get rid of loops and ensure right naming of vertices
g3 <- simplify(graph.data.frame(g2,directed = FALSE))



# Calcuate the maximal cliques - these are groupings where every node is connected to all others
cliq <- maximal.cliques(g3) # Solution from "majom" ()
cliq2 <- lapply(cliq, as.numeric)

# Reorder by level order - Solution from "MrFlick" ()
ml<-max(sapply(cliq, length))
reord <- do.call(order, data.frame(
  do.call(rbind, 
          lapply(cliq2, function(x) c(sort(x), rep.int(0, ml-length(x))))
  )
))
cliq <- cliq[reord]
cliq

# Generate labels to  factor levels
lab.txt <- vector(mode="list", n) # empty list
lab <- letters[seq(cliq)] # clique labels
for(i in seq(cliq)){ # loop to concatenate clique labels
  for(j in cliq[[i]]){
    lab.txt[[j]] <- paste0(lab.txt[[j]], lab[i])
  }
}
```

```
unlist(lab.txt)
[1] "a"  "ab" "ab" "b"
```

Comment: with the current igraph version `reord <- ... ` seems not to work:
Error in parse_op_args(..., what = "a vertex", is_fun = is_igraph_vs,  : 
  Not a vertex sequence

Comment: do not know if it is a good way, but can be fixed with

`cliq2 <- lapply(cliq, as.numeric)`
`reord <- do.call(... cliq2 ... )`

Answer (score 5):

Here's a possible solutions using `data.table`s very efficient `foverlaps` function. This is not exactly your desired output (because I'm not fully understand it) but you can identify the overlapping points from it

```
library(data.table)
setkey(setDT(test_data), CI_lower, CI_upper)
Overlaps <- foverlaps(test_data, test_data, type = "any", which = TRUE) ## returns overlap indices
test_data[ , overlaps := Overlaps[, paste(letters[yid], collapse = ""), xid]$V1][]
#    mean CI_lower CI_upper overlaps
# 1: 1.48     1.29     1.56      abc <~~ not overlapping with d
# 2: 1.59     1.38     1.84     abcd
# 3: 1.81     1.54     2.30     abcd
# 4: 1.94     1.62     2.59      bcd <~~ not overlapping with a
```

Comment: Thanks! this is indeed very close. Do you also have a good/efficient idea of how to remove the redundancy? Basically I guess it should always work if I remove the letters that are present in all entries and then re-numbers the remaining to start from a,b,c etc...